# Повторяющийся фон задаваемый символом?

Tags: css, css3, html5

Есть ли возможность средствами CSS задать фон из повторяющегося символа? (Разумеется не превращая данный символ в jpg, png, svg...)

Со спец символами не выходит, в реальном проекте.

```css
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width=%2224%22%20height=%2224%22%20viewBox=%220%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Ctext%20x=%220%22%20y=%2215%22%3E★%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я правильно понял, что "не превращая данный символ в jpg, png, svg...", это значает без конвертирования в графический формат? Вот вам "текстовое" решение. Подойдет? Inline-svg в данном случае должен быть сконвертирован в data-URI.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml, %3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20width=%2224%22%20height=%2224%22%20viewBox=%220%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Ctext%20x=%220%22%20y=%2215%22%3EQ%3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, это то что надо. А можешь объяснить что из этого является кодом буквы Q ? Или ты как-то это конвертируешь ?

Comment: В строчке c background-image нужно сделать поиск по ключу `Q`. Она ближе к концу находится.

Comment: А как быть если необходимо вставить спецсимвол, по типу ★ ?

Comment: В случае с `★` можно использовать как есть, просто скопируйте через буфер обмена. Но в принципе важно чтобы символ был кодирован в data-URI. Онлайн кодеры в этот формат можно найти в гугле.

Comment: Не могу понять, сделал как посоветовали, вставил через буфер. Сдесь на сайте отображает, а вот на проекте почему-то, нет. Я пробовал и Unicode код подставлять, да всё без толку http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm

Comment: Я же говорю, нужно кодировать в data-URI. Вот кодер http://foxtools.ru/UrlEncoder , кодировка UTF-8 должна быть для таких символов.

Comment: Спасибо. Наконец-то удалось 